# Accidental loss of trash icon on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: icons, trash

By deleting lots of files with shift+delete, I ended up without really figuring out how, with no more trash icon on Ubuntu 17.10 desktop. 
In Tweaks/Desktop/Icons on Desktop, "Trash" is still set to "On"...
How can I get the trashcan back?

Comment: Have you tried to set it to off and then back to on?

Comment: Yes, but it does not do the trick...

Comment: Are the overall icons on desktop maybe switched to off? Afaik there is no `trashcan.desktop` file under `~/desktop` even when you switch the trashcan on. Just tried myself.

Comment: "Show Icons" is turned on (I do see mounted volumes as expected). I just have no idea how I ended up vaporizing that trash icon...

Answer (score 0):

I Finally found out! The trash icon WAS on the desktop all along, but invisible because I have dual screens with different resolutions, that are aligned along the bottom. The trash icon was on top of the narrower screen, i.e. in the "not displayed" area of the smaller screen. Aligning the screens along the upper sides solved the problem.
It would be helpfull to have an automatic relocation of the icon when screen resolution puts them "out".